# Mapping not-so-entity-friendly legacy schema to entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

Okay, I'm really stuck with this one. Basically we've got a legacy table (+ normalization tables) in our database from which true domain entities should be created without altering the table schema. The table looks like this:

```
# identity table
| Domain (CK) | Group (CK) | Name (CK) | Password |
|-------------|------------|-----------|----------|
| root        |            |           |          |
| root        | group1     |           |          |
|             | group1     | someuser  | XXXXXX   |
|             | group2     |           |          |
|             |            | otheruser | XXXXXX   |

(CK = composite key)
```

The old application enforced the following rules:

- If only `Domain` is set, the entity is a *domain* which can contain users and groups
- If only `Group` is set, the entity is a *group* which can contain users
- If `Group` and `Domain` is set, the entity is a *group* within a *domain*
- If `Name` is set, the entity is a user within the respective *group* or *domain* (depending on which ones are set)
- etc. (I hope you get the picture).

What we would like to have in the end would be entities like this (pseudo):

```
class Domain {
    string Name;
    addUser(user);
    addGroup(group);
}

class Group {
    string Name;
    addUser(user);
}

class User {
    string Name;
    string Password;
}
```

The only two ways I can think of to resolve this would be either:

- Creating a base class of all three of the identity classes and creating a second mapping table containing a *discriminator*. But then: How could I tell EF that the *discriminator* is in a different table? And how could I enforce the business rules that e.g. an entity within that table having both a `Group` and a `Name` is a `User`?
- Creating repositories to do the whole job with mapping and stuff and denoting every business rule as pure application logic, but then there would be no way to incorporate EFs cool stuff like lazy loading, automatic mapping, LINQ etc. and we could basically continue using our legacy code. ;)

Specific questions:

- Is it possible to map a *discriminator* to a different table in EF?
- Is it possible to make that discriminator not a value, but rather conditional? (*E.g.* discriminator for *groups* => `hasValue(Group) && !hasValue(Name)`

Comment: This seems to be about user management. Is this your core domain (your application is all about domains, users and groups) or, as I suspect, a supporting subdomain ?

Comment: @guillaume31 Depends. Mostly, it's only used for auth and permission stuff, but AFAIK there are a few domain centric services who rely on that. (E.g. providing business logic based on the current user/permission). Why you ask? Because I should care less and do everything with POCOs and application logic if it's only infrastructure/AL stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to cheat a bit and not consider these as full blown domain entities. Instead you can treat user management as a separate subdomain with its own bounded context. Isolate the BC from the rest of your domain with an anticorruption layer that translates from the language of this BC to the language of the general domain. Typically, the AC layer will involve mappers from your old, badly designed classes to new `Domain`, `Group` and `User` classes.

I think this is the most sensible way to start benefiting from clean user management entities in your main domain straight away, while keeping options open for a complete makeover of your identity module and database (which should be I guess the ultimate goal).